# Cannot deploy to SSL on app server with DHF 5.2.1

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

In our environment we have a self-signed certificate template and the app servers on ports 8000, 8001, 8002, as well as our application app servers, are using that. We're using DHF 5.2.1.

When we try a deploy, it successfully deploys the database, app servers, and so on. Anything on ports 8000 or 8002 works fine. However, when it tries to use our app's final or staging ports, it fails (error messages below).

The gradle.properties file includes the following:

```
mlSimpleSsl=true
mlRestAuthentication=basic
```

The app server is using basic authentication with internal security. There are two errors we're seeing (sometimes one, sometimes the other).

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlLoadModules'.
> Caught exception before writing was completed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
```

or

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlLoadModules'.
> Caught exception before writing was completed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
```

Should `mlSimpleSsl` be sufficient here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ml-data-hub` doesn't honor `mlSimpleSsl` so it operates a little differently from `ml-gradle` and you won't need to use that property at all; instead you'll want to add (or they may already appear in `gradle.properties` commented-out) and set following properties:

```
mlManageSimpleSsl=true
mlManageScheme=https
mlAdminSimpleSsl=true
mlAdminScheme=https
mlAppServicesSimpleSsl=true
```

As well as the following, although you may want to add them to your environment-specific properties files:

```
mlJobAuth=basic
mlJobSimpleSsl=true

mlFinalAuth=basic
mlFinalSimpleSsl=true

mlStagingAuth=basic
mlStagingSimpleSsl=true
```

You'll most likely need to change authentication to "basic" on those app servers, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the additional properties to set TLS on those AppServers

```
mlStagingSimpleSsl=true
mlStagingAuth=basic

mlFinalSimpleSsl
mlFinalAuth=basic
```

https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.2/tools/gradle/gradle-properties.html